# Is it possible to resume web scraping in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have one PHP script which scrapes data from a site. It works fine but I want to handle errors.

I mean when an error occurs in data scraping at that time it would stop the execution and after I reload page it should be start from last where stopped not from beginning.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: What type of error?

Comment: If site from where i am scrapping gone down

Comment: Why don't you use `for` loop.

Comment: I think you can't get the point what i am asking

Comment: Please add a piece of code in your question

Comment: You have to code that. assuming you're looping through a list of html pages you are scraping, persistently store (in file, in database) a reference to the list index you last scraped, and start from that reference, or skip that and continue.